# How to implement saving in a Repository with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ddd-repositories

What I want is to implement the Repository pattern in a JPA/Hibernate application. I have a generic interface that describes the basic contract of my repositories:

```
public interface EntityRepository<Entity extends Object, EntityId> {
    Entity add(Entity entity);

    Entity byId(EntityId id);

    void remove(Entity entity);

    void removeById(EntityId id);

    void save();

    List<Entity> toList();
}
```

And here is an implementation of such an interface:

```
public class EntityRepositoryHibernate<Entity extends Object, EntityId>
       implements Serializable,
                  EntityRepository<Entity, EntityId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    protected Class<Entity> entityClass;

    public EntityRepositoryHibernate(Class<Entity> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Entity add(Entity entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Entity byId(EntityId id) {
        DetachedCriteria criteria = criteriaDAO.createDetachedCriteria(entityClass);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
        return (Entity)criteriaDAO.executeCriteriaUniqueResult(criteria);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Entity entity) {
        if(entity==null)
            return;
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeById(EntityId id) {
        remove(byId(id));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Entity> toList() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("toList() not implemented in "+entityClass.getName()); 
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}
```

All methods are working fine, except `save()`, so this is the focus here.

As far as I understand, Hibernate is able to track all changes in any instance returned by a query (the `byId()` method). So, the idea of the `save()` method is to save any instances that where retrieved and changed, that's why the method does not receives any parameters, it is supposed to save everything that has to be saved (which means, any persistent instance that was retrived and somehow updated while the repository lives.

In a possible scenario, I could call `byId()` 10 times to retrieve 10 different instances and change only 4 of them. The idea is that by calling `save()` once, those 4 instances would be saved in the data server.

Problem is when I call `flush()` I receive an exception stating that there is no transaction active. Since I'm using a JTA persistence unit, it's illegal to open the transation programatically by calling `entityManager.getTransaction()`.

Considering that, what to do to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems that your are missunderstanding the purpose of `EntityManager.flush` method. It doesn't commit any changes managed by persistence context, just sends SQL instructuions to the database. I mean, for the same JTA transaction, when you retrieve and modify some entity instances the changes/SQL instructions are cached waiting to be sent to the database. If the underlying transaction is commited this changes are **flushed** to the database along with the commit instruction. If you invoke `flush` before transaction is commited, only flush the changes until the invokation point (well, some SQL instruction could have been flushed previously by reasons out of this matter) but not the commit instruction is sent.

**How to fixed?**

I suggest you to don't mix [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) with Transaction manipulation.

Looks like you are using Container Managed Transactions ([javaee tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm#BNBQW)) so just erase the `save` method and let container to manage the transactions. This will change your focus, you now have to care about rolling back transactions ([throwing exception or invoking `setRollbackOnly`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm#BNBQW)) but you don't need to explicit commmit.

Comment: Thank you for your orientations, but I have some doubts about it. I read the part on Container-managed entity manangers. The link you sugested tells me that I have to anotate the entityManager existing in the repository with `@PersistenceContext`. You said to remove the `save()` method but what will trigger the saving? Imagine I have a web page in a JSF application and change a lot of fields that change a lot of values in a bean. The I click the save button. What will command the saving of all my changes if I don't have a `save()`method anymore?

Comment: If the entities are tracked by the persistence context, the changes are save when the underlying transaction commits. You must be sure that the transaction exists and the **entities are attached state to it**. I mean, you maybe retrieve the instances with `byId` method but do the changes outside of a transactional scope, so your instances are *detached* (not tracked by any persistence context) and no change will be save at least you track/attache the instance again. What javaee specifications are you using? Are you just using CDI beans?

Comment: It depends on how are you dealing with the transactional scopes but if your ` EntityRepository`'s method are CRUD transactional you could simply add an `update` method that receive the entity and attach it to the persistence context using `entityMamager.merge`. BTW, is strange that all your methods work excepting the `save` because `remove`, `persist` also need to be transaction scoped, maybe your framework doesn't init the transaction until is really needed...

Comment: Thanks for your information, but things are not clear to me yet. Indeed I retrieve the instances with `byId()`. If they are in the transaction scope or now, I can't say. I certainly did not do anything to make that happen. What I had to do to get closer to what I want is to have an overloaded version of `save()` that receives the entity and use the Hibernate session to call `saveOrUpdate()`. It worked perfectly, but in this case I am tracking the objects that need to be saved, and the ideal was to abstract that, by using some kind of unit of work. It's a start, but not precisely what I want.

Comment: I understand what you wanna achieve but entityManager and the underlying persistence context by default lives and dies within a JTA transaction. Once the transaction is finished, all persistent objects are *detached* from the entityManager and are no longer tracked. So you must know how the JTA transaction are working in your application, when start and ends, when you need to attach entities to a new transaction/persistence context, etc. I suggest read https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm#BNBQW and add more details about you app: EJB, who invoke repository, Backin